# SQL: query all tables in database for field and return table, field, field description in query results

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-python

This is my first stack overflow question.

I am trying to query a MySQL database containing multiple tables for a specific field if it exists. Unfortunately for me, I am working with a database where different field values could mean different things.

That part is fine, But I also need to return the table name in the query results. There is a growing amount of tables. This is the part I'm getting stuck on.

Here is what I have tried.

```
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'test_db'
            SELECT IF( EXISTS(
                 SELECT col_name, description
                 FROM table_name
                 WHERE col_name = field_value)) ;
```

My logic (please assist if flawed, I am here to learn!)

1. First query selects all tables in database to query
2. subquery only returns those tables that have the field that I am searching for, along with their description.

I would like my results to look something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
             query results
------------------------------------------------
table_name | query_field_val | field_description
-------------------------------------------------
table1     | foo             | foo is foo
-------------------------------------------------
table2     | foo             | foo is not bar
-------------------------------------------------
table3     | foo             | foo is in foobar
```

Here is a table structure example (there is a growing number of tables, so I would prefer not to hard code table names if at all possible)
Every table is a result of another table in a different database. It contains all of the column values and description. The description is NOT related to the schema and it just a string

```
---------------------------
          table_1
---------------------------
   col_values | desc
---------------------------
 foo          | foo foo foo
---------------------------
 bar          | bar bar bar
---------------------------
 foobar       | foobar foo
```

---

```
          table_2
---------------------------
   col_values | desc
---------------------------
 foo          | not bar
---------------------------
 foobar       | bar in bar
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

I hope this was descriptive enough! Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: could you explain what field_description is or where to find it. here is nothing of that kind https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html

Comment: Hello, I described field_description in the original question as just a data type of VARCHAR.

Comment: you question is somewhat unclear. , you can do this in  a procedure Where You loo over the solution given in the answer, and running over all resluts.

Comment: There may not be a way to get exactly what you have stated.  So, pleas explain what you need to do with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test_db' AND column_name = 'col_name';
```

Comment: This would only return the tables, right? I am looking to return the table names, col_name , and descriptions from those tables.

Comment: Hi @paulinusia, but the values of col_name and descriptions should be more than 1, so how you want them to appear in a single row with table_name?